# How To Extract specific Frame using AForge Library

Tags: c#, video, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing

I'm trying to extract a specific frame from a video file.  I have a frame that I want when I play a video file with the aforge library.  I call a new frame event, and if the new frame matches my specific frame, then it shows me a message: "Frame Match".  This specific frame randomly appears in a video file.  Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IVideoSource videoSource = new FileVideoSource(@"e:\media\test\a.mkv");
    playerControl.VideoSource = videoSource;
    playerControl.Start( );
    videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(Video_NewFrame );
}

private void Video_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //Create Bitmap from frame
    Bitmap FrameData = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
    //Add to PictureBox
    pictureBox1.Image   = FrameData;
    //compare current frame to specific fram
    if (pictureBox1.Image == pictureBox2.Image)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Frame Match");  
    }
}
```

pictureBox2.image is a fixed frame that I want to match.  This code is working fine when I play video files and extract new frames, but I am unable to compare new frames to specific frames.  Please guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions

```
var capture = new FileCapture(@"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv");
capture.Open();
capture.Seek(<yourFrameIndex>, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var image = capture.ReadAs<Bgr, byte>();
```

or you can use standard IEnumerable like:

```
var capture = new FileCapture(@"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv");
capture.Open();
var image = capture.ElementAt(<yourFrameIndex>); //will actually just cast image
```

Examples are included.

moved to: https://github.com/dajuric/dot-imaging

Comment: Really nice, @dajuric! I'm trying to do this right now, but I seem unable to convert the return type to ImageSource or Bitmap. How do I work with that Image<Bgr8>? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also, I'm getting this exception when creating the FileCapture instance: Cannot load DLL file 'opencv_highgui248'. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your problem the issue is that you can't compare image to image this way. I think you will find that the way to do this is to build a histogram table and then compare image histograms.

Some of the related things to look into are:

[how to compare two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647811/how-to-compare-two-images)

[image comparer class form VS 2015 unit testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191601.aspx)

The second one is from unit testing library so not sure of performance (haven't tried myself yet)